# how to make a subprocess when called execute specific task

Tags: python

Hi I have a subprocess that I call in my code this subprocess is Nasgro a GUi that I did not build or code  know I can call the subprocess with no problem but I would like the subprocess execute some function for me  not just to open

```
  direction=QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,"Pick a folder")

     #looking for the exe of eCRPR
     for element in os.listdir(direction):
         if element.endswith('nasgro90.exe'):
             #creating a variable of name process and having type QProcess giving by Pyqt
             process =QProcess(self)
             # join the main path and the exe file so we can give it to subprocess.call
             path2=''.join((direction,'\\',element))
             #opining nasgro
             process.start(path2)
```

this is how I call the process and the GUI show up ( see picture )[image: GUI description here]

and what I would like is that when I call the subprocess he  use NASFLA without me clicking it (see picture 2)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write something in [Pywinauto](https://pywinauto.github.io/) to interact with the GUI. They have some nice [examples](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#look-at-the-examples) you could look at.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will look for it   :)